# Is it possible to test SVG elements using Javascript libraries? Any other options?

Tags: javascript, svg, automated-tests, ui-automation

For displaying workflows (block diagrams with arrows and collapsible panels) in a browser (Firefox, Chrome), "SVG" is being used by developers.

My requirement is to test the workflow is correctly rendered in browser UI. So far, I have tried different tools, and saw there is a little bit of support for SVG through Selenium and Ranorex, but not all actions are supported.

Some of the testing scenarios include:

1. Verifying Panels & Breadscrums
2. First Panel Minimized by default
3. Verifying Jgraph by clicking collapse button
4. Verifying all Rectangular box object and along with text, in sequential order
5. Verifying Phases alignment such as horizontally or vertically.
6. Verify connections between actions/rectangular blocks
7. Verifying color code on each rectangular boxes
8. Finding out shortest path between boxes

I am sure that Javascript can be used to access the SVG elements, but not sure of any javascript automation libraries around SVG.

Any suggestions on test approach?

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is not much more than you already found in Selenium or other tools. 
Most likely you'll have to code a lot of JavaScript around it to get some test automation done...

Here is a good article
http://sny.no/2011/10/svg-game.html

And there are certain JavaScript libraries which support svg editing like this one:
https://svgdotjs.github.io/